# Sortable & Droppable JQuery Navigation

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a navigation menu with bootstrap 3.0 that has sortable "Tabs" which is working. What I am trying to implement is the ability to drag the sortable "Tabs" into the "drop down" menu and back again which also contains sortable list items.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

I have created a Fiddle here:

```
  >http://jsfiddle.net/nkBNP/48/
```

to try and explain a little better.

I hope someone can help me!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should use the "accept" function provided by JQuery to choose which elements will be handled by the droppable element.

Then, you should define an event to get that you are dragging/sorting an element. jQuery provided the start function to do that. When it fires, you should show the dropdown programmatically so that you can drop it there.

You should also see how JQuery handles this (and perhaps use it): http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists-through-tabs

It requires some hacking...
Some pseudo code:

```
var droppable = $('#my_droppable'); // the dropdown is hidden!

droppable.droppable({
    accept: '.mySortable'
});

$('.mySortable').sortable({
   start: function(){
      droppable.show();
   },

   stop:function(){
      droppable.hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I can't seem to get it to work still agh! If you could edit my fiddle and get it working that would be great! If you can get it working I will send you some cash via paypal for the help! thanks

Comment: Anyone help me with this??